# Why cannot I have a usual dataframe after using pivot()?

Tags: pandas, pivot, pivot-table

Under the variable names, there is an extra row that I do not want in my data set

```
fdi_autocracy = fdi_autocracy.pivot(index=["Country", "regime", "Year"], 
                                    columns="partner_regime",
                                    values =['FDI_outward', "FDI_inward", "total_fdi"],
                                   ).reset_index()
```

```
                 Country   regime  Year   FDI_outward FDI_inward total_fdi
partner_regime                               0.0        0.0       0.0
0                Albania    0.0  1995         NaN        NaN       NaN
1                Albania    0.0  1996         NaN        NaN       NaN
2                Albania    0.0  1997         NaN        NaN       NaN
3                Albania    0.0  1998         NaN        NaN       NaN
4                Albania    0.0  1999         NaN        NaN       NaN
```

What I want is following:

```
                 Country   regime  Year   FDI_outward FDI_inward total_fdi
                                       
0                Albania    0.0  1995         NaN        NaN       NaN
1                Albania    0.0  1996         NaN        NaN       NaN
2                Albania    0.0  1997         NaN        NaN       NaN
3                Albania    0.0  1998         NaN        NaN       NaN
4                Albania    0.0  1999         NaN        NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you don't need the partner_regime?
this removes that title

```
fdi_autocracy.rename_axis(columns=[None, None])
```

Comment: It gives following error: rename_axis() got an unexpected keyword argument "column"

Comment: had a typo, its columns (plural form), updated the answer

Comment: But now the error cahgned. Error: Must pass list-like as `names`.

Comment: It does not really. Three none did not work, how many times should I exactly write? Please could you help?

Comment: I tried on the dummy test data here with me. Last attempt from my side, make it only twice. I updated the answer

Comment: But still 0s are there, no?

Comment: if you provide data to reproduce, I'll be able to try and validate.